# Python - Check that all delimiters are matched and closed

Tags: python, delimiter

I am trying to write a Python program that takes a string and checks whether all delimiters have been matched and closed.

I found [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150771/check-if-all-of-the-delimiters-in-an-expression-are-matched-and-closed?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) program that does this, but sadly it does not work for string quotes. Unfortunately I don't completely understand how the program works, so I can't fix it. Can someone tell me how to change the program to work for string delimiters (' and ").

The current code I have is:

```
delimOpens = ['[', ']', '(', ')', '{', '}', '"', "'"]
delimCloseToOpen = {']':'[', ')':'(', '}':'{', '"':'"', "'":"'"}

def check_match(source):
    delimStack = ['sentinel']
    for c in source:
        if c in delimOpens:
            delimStack.append(c)
        elif c in delimCloseToOpen:
            if delimCloseToOpen[c] != delimStack.pop():
                return False
    return (len(delimStack) == 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(check_match('{(abc)22}[14(xyz)2]'))
    print(check_match('[ { ] }'))
    print(check_match('{ (x) } ['))
    print(check_match('This is "hello" world'))
    print(check_match('This is "hello world'))
```

The issue is that the code returns false for the valid string:

```
print(check_match('This is "hello" world'))
```

Comment: How do you distinguish between an *opening* `"` and a *closing* `"`?

Comment: The fact that each opening one needs a closing one.

Comment: You are pushing a `"` on the stack when you encounter the closing `"`.

Comment: This is a common example when students are learning stack...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pushing a `"` on the stack even when you encounter a closing `"`.

Solution: do an early check if the current character can close something and that something is in the stack top (`delimStack[-1]`):

```
delimOpens = ['[', ']', '(', ')', '{', '}', '"', "'"]
delimCloseToOpen = {']':'[', ')':'(', '}':'{', '"':'"', "'":"'"}

def check_match(source):
    delimStack = ['sentinel']
    for c in source:
        if c in delimCloseToOpen and delimCloseToOpen[c] == delimStack[-1]:
            delimStack.pop()
        elif c in delimOpens:
            delimStack.append(c)
        elif c in delimCloseToOpen:
            if delimCloseToOpen[c] != delimStack.pop():
                return False
    return (len(delimStack) == 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(check_match('{(abc)22}[14(xyz)2]'))
    print(check_match('[ { ] }'))
    print(check_match('{ (x) } ['))
    print(check_match('This is "hello" world'))
    print(check_match('This is "hello world'))
```

Output:

```
$ python3 so_50153245.py
True
False
False
True
False
```

Comment: Sadly your solution also returns False for my test case.

Comment: I'm still getting False with your code. Are you sure you changed it?

Comment: What does delimStack[-1] do?

Comment: @Superdooperhero: are you sure you are trying my code? I attached output of my code and it works as expected.

Comment: I copied your code about 3 times, all returned False

Comment: Copied your new full program, still getting False

Comment: @Superdooperhero: I don't know what's going on with you and your computer. My output is consistent with this https://ideone.com/ef9lYB. You are clearly doing something wrong.